# How to find unknowns $w_1,w_2,w_3$ that satisfy $t=w_1f_1 + w_2f_2 + w_3f_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

For any $i \in \{1,2,3\}$, let:

- $w_i \in [0,1]$ is an *unknown* number such that $\sum_{i \in \{1,2,3\}} w_i = 1$.
- $t$ is a *known* number in $[0,1]$. Suppose that $t = 0.8$.
- $f_i$ is also a *known* number in $[0,1]$. Suppose that $f_1 = 0.2$, $f_2=0.6$, and $f_3=0.5$.

Which are related by the equation: $t = \sum_{i \in \{1,2,3\}} w_i \times f_i$. It is assumed that there is only one true solution, and the rest are not true (maybe close estimations).

The questions are:

- What are the possible values of $w_1, w_2, w_3$ that satisfy the equation above?
- How to find them?
- In case too many possible values exist, what is the best method in estimating the values of $w_1,w_2,w_3$?

### A brute-force by Python

By brute-forcing answers, I found these which give a priority to ensuring that the sum $w_1+w_2+w_3=1$ (without ensuring that $t=0.8$):

```
w1, w2, w3, w1+w2+w3, t
0, 0.01, 0.99, 1.0, 0.501
0, 0.02, 0.98, 1.0, 0.502
0, 0.02, 0.99, 1.01, 0.507
0, 0.03, 0.98, 1.01, 0.508
0, 0.03, 0.99, 1.02, 0.513
0, 0.04, 0.98, 1.02, 0.514
0, 0.04, 0.99, 1.03, 0.519
0, 0.05, 0.98, 1.03, 0.52
0, 0.05, 0.99, 1.04, 0.525
0, 0.06, 0.98, 1.04, 0.526
0, 0.06, 0.99, 1.05, 0.531
0, 0.07, 0.98, 1.05, 0.532
0, 0.07, 0.99, 1.06, 0.537
0, 0.08, 0.98, 1.06, 0.538
0, 0.08, 0.99, 1.07, 0.543
0, 0.09, 0.98, 1.07, 0.544
0, 0.09, 0.99, 1.08, 0.549
0, 0.1, 0.98, 1.08, 0.55
0, 0.1, 0.99, 1.09, 0.555
0, 0.11, 0.98, 1.09, 0.556
```

There are solutions, but none of them correspond to a $t$ that is close enough to 0.8.

Here I gave a high priority to ensuring that $t=0.8$ (while ignoring the sum = 1):

```
w1, w2, w3, w1+w2+w3, t
0, 0.51, 0.99, 1.5, 0.801
0, 0.55, 0.94, 1.49, 0.8
0, 0.6, 0.88, 1.48, 0.8
0, 0.65, 0.82, 1.47, 0.8
0, 0.7, 0.76, 1.46, 0.8
0, 0.75, 0.7, 1.45, 0.8
0, 0.8, 0.64, 1.44, 0.8
0, 0.85, 0.58, 1.43, 0.8
0, 0.9, 0.52, 1.42, 0.8
0, 0.95, 0.46, 1.41, 0.8
0.01, 0.53, 0.96, 1.5, 0.8
0.01, 0.58, 0.9, 1.49, 0.8
0.01, 0.63, 0.84, 1.48, 0.8
0.01, 0.68, 0.78, 1.47, 0.8
0.01, 0.73, 0.72, 1.46, 0.8
0.01, 0.78, 0.66, 1.45, 0.8
0.01, 0.83, 0.6, 1.44, 0.8
0.04, 0.82, 0.6, 1.46, 0.8
0.06, 0.83, 0.58, 1.47, 0.8
0.07, 0.81, 0.6, 1.48, 0.8
0.09, 0.82, 0.58, 1.49, 0.8
0.1, 0.8, 0.6, 1.5, 0.8
0.11, 0.83, 0.56, 1.5, 0.8
0.12, 0.81, 0.58, 1.51, 0.8
0.13, 0.54, 0.9, 1.57, 0.8
0.13, 0.59, 0.84, 1.56, 0.8
0.13, 0.64, 0.78, 1.55, 0.8
0.13, 0.69, 0.72, 1.54, 0.8
0.13, 0.74, 0.66, 1.53, 0.8
0.13, 0.79, 0.6, 1.52, 0.8
0.14, 0.52, 0.92, 1.58, 0.8
0.14, 0.57, 0.86, 1.57, 0.8
0.14, 0.62, 0.8, 1.56, 0.8
0.14, 0.67, 0.74, 1.55, 0.8
0.14, 0.72, 0.68, 1.54, 0.8
0.14, 0.77, 0.62, 1.53, 0.8
0.14, 0.82, 0.56, 1.52, 0.8
0.15, 0.5, 0.94, 1.59, 0.8
0.15, 0.55, 0.88, 1.58, 0.8
0.15, 0.6, 0.82, 1.57, 0.8
0.15, 0.65, 0.76, 1.56, 0.8
0.15, 0.7, 0.7, 1.55, 0.8
0.15, 0.75, 0.64, 1.54, 0.8
0.15, 0.8, 0.58, 1.53, 0.8
0.16, 0.53, 0.9, 1.59, 0.8
0.16, 0.58, 0.84, 1.58, 0.8
0.16, 0.63, 0.78, 1.57, 0.8
0.16, 0.68, 0.72, 1.56, 0.8
0.16, 0.73, 0.66, 1.55, 0.8
0.16, 0.78, 0.6, 1.54, 0.8
0.16, 0.83, 0.54, 1.53, 0.8
0.17, 0.51, 0.92, 1.6, 0.8
0.17, 0.56, 0.86, 1.59, 0.8
0.17, 0.61, 0.8, 1.58, 0.8
0.17, 0.66, 0.74, 1.57, 0.8
0.17, 0.71, 0.68, 1.56, 0.8
0.17, 0.76, 0.62, 1.55, 0.8
0.17, 0.81, 0.56, 1.54, 0.8
0.18, 0.54, 0.88, 1.6, 0.8
0.18, 0.59, 0.82, 1.59, 0.8
0.18, 0.64, 0.76, 1.58, 0.8
0.18, 0.69, 0.7, 1.57, 0.8
0.18, 0.74, 0.64, 1.56, 0.8
0.18, 0.79, 0.58, 1.55, 0.8
0.19, 0.52, 0.9, 1.61, 0.8
0.19, 0.57, 0.84, 1.6, 0.8
0.19, 0.62, 0.78, 1.59, 0.8
0.19, 0.67, 0.72, 1.58, 0.8
0.19, 0.72, 0.66, 1.57, 0.8
0.19, 0.77, 0.6, 1.56, 0.8
0.19, 0.82, 0.54, 1.55, 0.8
0.2, 0.5, 0.92, 1.62, 0.8
0.2, 0.55, 0.86, 1.61, 0.8
0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1.6, 0.8
0.2, 0.65, 0.74, 1.59, 0.8
0.2, 0.7, 0.68, 1.58, 0.8
0.2, 0.75, 0.62, 1.57, 0.8
0.2, 0.8, 0.56, 1.56, 0.8
0.21, 0.53, 0.88, 1.62, 0.8
0.21, 0.58, 0.82, 1.61, 0.8
0.21, 0.63, 0.76, 1.6, 0.8
0.21, 0.68, 0.7, 1.59, 0.8
0.21, 0.73, 0.64, 1.58, 0.8
0.21, 0.78, 0.58, 1.57, 0.8
0.21, 0.83, 0.52, 1.56, 0.8
0.22, 0.51, 0.9, 1.63, 0.8
0.22, 0.56, 0.84, 1.62, 0.8
0.22, 0.61, 0.78, 1.61, 0.8
0.22, 0.66, 0.72, 1.6, 0.8
0.22, 0.71, 0.66, 1.59, 0.8
0.22, 0.76, 0.6, 1.58, 0.8
0.22, 0.81, 0.54, 1.57, 0.8
0.23, 0.54, 0.86, 1.63, 0.8
0.23, 0.59, 0.8, 1.62, 0.8
0.23, 0.64, 0.74, 1.61, 0.8
0.23, 0.69, 0.68, 1.6, 0.8
0.23, 0.74, 0.62, 1.59, 0.8
0.23, 0.79, 0.56, 1.58, 0.8
0.24, 0.52, 0.88, 1.64, 0.8
0.24, 0.57, 0.82, 1.63, 0.8
0.24, 0.62, 0.76, 1.62, 0.8
0.24, 0.67, 0.7, 1.61, 0.8
0.24, 0.72, 0.64, 1.6, 0.8
0.24, 0.77, 0.58, 1.59, 0.8
0.24, 0.82, 0.52, 1.58, 0.8
0.25, 0.5, 0.9, 1.65, 0.8
0.25, 0.55, 0.84, 1.64, 0.8
0.25, 0.6, 0.78, 1.63, 0.8
0.25, 0.65, 0.72, 1.62, 0.8
0.25, 0.7, 0.66, 1.61, 0.8
0.25, 0.75, 0.6, 1.6, 0.8
0.25, 0.8, 0.54, 1.59, 0.8
0.26, 0.53, 0.86, 1.65, 0.8
0.26, 0.58, 0.8, 1.64, 0.8
0.26, 0.63, 0.74, 1.63, 0.8
0.26, 0.68, 0.68, 1.62, 0.8
0.26, 0.73, 0.62, 1.61, 0.8
0.26, 0.78, 0.56, 1.6, 0.8
0.26, 0.83, 0.5, 1.59, 0.8
0.27, 0.51, 0.88, 1.66, 0.8
0.27, 0.56, 0.82, 1.65, 0.8
0.27, 0.61, 0.76, 1.64, 0.8
0.27, 0.66, 0.7, 1.63, 0.8
0.27, 0.71, 0.64, 1.62, 0.8
0.27, 0.76, 0.58, 1.61, 0.8
0.27, 0.81, 0.52, 1.6, 0.8
0.28, 0.54, 0.84, 1.66, 0.8
0.28, 0.59, 0.78, 1.65, 0.8
0.28, 0.64, 0.72, 1.64, 0.8
0.28, 0.69, 0.66, 1.63, 0.8
0.28, 0.74, 0.6, 1.62, 0.8
0.28, 0.79, 0.54, 1.61, 0.8
0.29, 0.52, 0.86, 1.67, 0.8
0.29, 0.57, 0.8, 1.66, 0.8
0.29, 0.62, 0.74, 1.65, 0.8
0.29, 0.67, 0.68, 1.64, 0.8
0.29, 0.72, 0.62, 1.63, 0.8
0.29, 0.77, 0.56, 1.62, 0.8
0.29, 0.82, 0.5, 1.61, 0.8
0.3, 0.5, 0.88, 1.68, 0.8
0.3, 0.55, 0.82, 1.67, 0.8
0.3, 0.6, 0.76, 1.66, 0.8
0.3, 0.65, 0.7, 1.65, 0.8
0.3, 0.7, 0.64, 1.64, 0.8
0.3, 0.75, 0.58, 1.63, 0.8
0.3, 0.8, 0.52, 1.62, 0.8
0.31, 0.53, 0.84, 1.68, 0.8
0.31, 0.58, 0.78, 1.67, 0.8
0.31, 0.63, 0.72, 1.66, 0.8
0.31, 0.68, 0.66, 1.65, 0.8
0.31, 0.73, 0.6, 1.64, 0.8
0.31, 0.78, 0.54, 1.63, 0.8
0.31, 0.83, 0.48, 1.62, 0.8
0.32, 0.51, 0.86, 1.69, 0.8
0.32, 0.56, 0.8, 1.68, 0.8
0.32, 0.61, 0.74, 1.67, 0.8
0.32, 0.66, 0.68, 1.66, 0.8
0.32, 0.71, 0.62, 1.65, 0.8
0.32, 0.76, 0.56, 1.64, 0.8
0.32, 0.81, 0.5, 1.63, 0.8
0.33, 0.54, 0.82, 1.69, 0.8
0.33, 0.59, 0.76, 1.68, 0.8
0.33, 0.64, 0.7, 1.67, 0.8
0.33, 0.69, 0.64, 1.66, 0.8
0.33, 0.74, 0.58, 1.65, 0.8
0.33, 0.79, 0.52, 1.64, 0.8
0.34, 0.52, 0.84, 1.7, 0.8
0.34, 0.57, 0.78, 1.69, 0.8
0.34, 0.62, 0.72, 1.68, 0.8
0.34, 0.67, 0.66, 1.67, 0.8
0.34, 0.72, 0.6, 1.66, 0.8
0.34, 0.77, 0.54, 1.65, 0.8
0.34, 0.82, 0.48, 1.64, 0.8
0.35, 0.5, 0.86, 1.71, 0.8
0.35, 0.55, 0.8, 1.7, 0.8
0.35, 0.6, 0.74, 1.69, 0.8
0.35, 0.65, 0.68, 1.68, 0.8
0.35, 0.7, 0.62, 1.67, 0.8
0.35, 0.75, 0.56, 1.66, 0.8
0.35, 0.8, 0.5, 1.65, 0.8
0.36, 0.53, 0.82, 1.71, 0.8
0.36, 0.58, 0.76, 1.7, 0.8
0.36, 0.63, 0.7, 1.69, 0.8
0.36, 0.68, 0.64, 1.68, 0.8
0.36, 0.73, 0.58, 1.67, 0.8
0.36, 0.78, 0.52, 1.66, 0.8
0.36, 0.83, 0.46, 1.65, 0.8
0.37, 0.51, 0.84, 1.72, 0.8
0.37, 0.56, 0.78, 1.71, 0.8
0.37, 0.61, 0.72, 1.7, 0.8
0.37, 0.66, 0.66, 1.69, 0.8
0.37, 0.71, 0.6, 1.68, 0.8
0.37, 0.76, 0.54, 1.67, 0.8
0.37, 0.81, 0.48, 1.66, 0.8
0.38, 0.54, 0.8, 1.72, 0.8
0.38, 0.59, 0.74, 1.71, 0.8
0.38, 0.64, 0.68, 1.7, 0.8
0.38, 0.69, 0.62, 1.69, 0.8
0.38, 0.74, 0.56, 1.68, 0.8
0.38, 0.79, 0.5, 1.67, 0.8
0.39, 0.52, 0.82, 1.73, 0.8
0.39, 0.57, 0.76, 1.72, 0.8
0.39, 0.62, 0.7, 1.71, 0.8
0.39, 0.67, 0.64, 1.7, 0.8
0.39, 0.72, 0.58, 1.69, 0.8
0.39, 0.77, 0.52, 1.68, 0.8
0.39, 0.82, 0.46, 1.67, 0.8
0.4, 0.5, 0.84, 1.74, 0.8
0.4, 0.55, 0.78, 1.73, 0.8
0.4, 0.6, 0.72, 1.72, 0.8
0.4, 0.65, 0.66, 1.71, 0.8
0.4, 0.7, 0.6, 1.7, 0.8
0.4, 0.75, 0.54, 1.69, 0.8
0.4, 0.8, 0.48, 1.68, 0.8
0.41, 0.53, 0.8, 1.74, 0.8
0.41, 0.58, 0.74, 1.73, 0.8
0.41, 0.63, 0.68, 1.72, 0.8
0.41, 0.68, 0.62, 1.71, 0.8
0.41, 0.73, 0.56, 1.7, 0.8
0.41, 0.78, 0.5, 1.69, 0.8
0.41, 0.83, 0.44, 1.68, 0.8
0.42, 0.51, 0.82, 1.75, 0.8
0.42, 0.56, 0.76, 1.74, 0.8
0.42, 0.61, 0.7, 1.73, 0.8
0.42, 0.66, 0.64, 1.72, 0.8
0.42, 0.71, 0.58, 1.71, 0.8
0.42, 0.76, 0.52, 1.7, 0.8
0.42, 0.81, 0.46, 1.69, 0.8
0.43, 0.54, 0.78, 1.75, 0.8
0.43, 0.59, 0.72, 1.74, 0.8
0.43, 0.64, 0.66, 1.73, 0.8
0.43, 0.69, 0.6, 1.72, 0.8
0.43, 0.74, 0.54, 1.71, 0.8
0.43, 0.79, 0.48, 1.7, 0.8
0.44, 0.52, 0.8, 1.76, 0.8
0.44, 0.57, 0.74, 1.75, 0.8
0.44, 0.62, 0.68, 1.74, 0.8
0.44, 0.67, 0.62, 1.73, 0.8
0.44, 0.72, 0.56, 1.72, 0.8
0.44, 0.77, 0.5, 1.71, 0.8
0.44, 0.82, 0.44, 1.7, 0.8
0.45, 0.5, 0.82, 1.77, 0.8
0.45, 0.55, 0.76, 1.76, 0.8
0.45, 0.6, 0.7, 1.75, 0.8
0.45, 0.65, 0.64, 1.74, 0.8
0.45, 0.7, 0.58, 1.73, 0.8
0.45, 0.75, 0.52, 1.72, 0.8
0.45, 0.8, 0.46, 1.71, 0.8
0.46, 0.53, 0.78, 1.77, 0.8
0.46, 0.58, 0.72, 1.76, 0.8
0.46, 0.63, 0.66, 1.75, 0.8
0.46, 0.68, 0.6, 1.74, 0.8
0.46, 0.73, 0.54, 1.73, 0.8
0.46, 0.78, 0.48, 1.72, 0.8
0.46, 0.83, 0.42, 1.71, 0.8
0.47, 0.51, 0.8, 1.78, 0.8
0.47, 0.56, 0.74, 1.77, 0.8
0.47, 0.61, 0.68, 1.76, 0.8
0.47, 0.66, 0.62, 1.75, 0.8
0.47, 0.71, 0.56, 1.74, 0.8
0.47, 0.76, 0.5, 1.73, 0.8
0.47, 0.81, 0.44, 1.72, 0.8
0.48, 0.54, 0.76, 1.78, 0.8
0.48, 0.59, 0.7, 1.77, 0.8
0.48, 0.64, 0.64, 1.76, 0.8
0.48, 0.69, 0.58, 1.75, 0.8
0.48, 0.74, 0.52, 1.74, 0.8
0.48, 0.79, 0.46, 1.73, 0.8
0.49, 0.52, 0.78, 1.79, 0.8
0.49, 0.57, 0.72, 1.78, 0.8
0.49, 0.62, 0.66, 1.77, 0.8
0.49, 0.67, 0.6, 1.76, 0.8
0.49, 0.72, 0.54, 1.75, 0.8
0.49, 0.77, 0.48, 1.74, 0.8
0.49, 0.82, 0.42, 1.73, 0.8
0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 1.8, 0.8
0.5, 0.55, 0.74, 1.79, 0.8
0.5, 0.6, 0.68, 1.78, 0.8
0.5, 0.65, 0.62, 1.77, 0.8
0.5, 0.7, 0.56, 1.76, 0.8
0.5, 0.75, 0.5, 1.75, 0.8
0.5, 0.8, 0.44, 1.74, 0.8
0.51, 0.53, 0.76, 1.8, 0.8
0.51, 0.58, 0.7, 1.79, 0.8
0.51, 0.63, 0.64, 1.78, 0.8
0.51, 0.68, 0.58, 1.77, 0.8
0.51, 0.73, 0.52, 1.76, 0.8
0.51, 0.78, 0.46, 1.75, 0.8
0.51, 0.83, 0.4, 1.74, 0.8
0.52, 0.51, 0.78, 1.81, 0.8
0.52, 0.56, 0.72, 1.8, 0.8
0.52, 0.61, 0.66, 1.79, 0.8
0.52, 0.66, 0.6, 1.78, 0.8
0.52, 0.71, 0.54, 1.77, 0.8
0.52, 0.76, 0.48, 1.76, 0.8
0.52, 0.81, 0.42, 1.75, 0.8
0.53, 0.54, 0.74, 1.81, 0.8
0.53, 0.59, 0.68, 1.8, 0.8
0.53, 0.64, 0.62, 1.79, 0.8
0.53, 0.69, 0.56, 1.78, 0.8
0.53, 0.74, 0.5, 1.77, 0.8
0.53, 0.79, 0.44, 1.76, 0.8
0.54, 0.52, 0.76, 1.82, 0.8
0.54, 0.57, 0.7, 1.81, 0.8
0.54, 0.62, 0.64, 1.8, 0.8
0.54, 0.67, 0.58, 1.79, 0.8
0.54, 0.72, 0.52, 1.78, 0.8
0.54, 0.77, 0.46, 1.77, 0.8
0.54, 0.82, 0.4, 1.76, 0.8
0.55, 0.5, 0.78, 1.83, 0.8
0.55, 0.55, 0.72, 1.82, 0.8
0.55, 0.6, 0.66, 1.81, 0.8
0.55, 0.65, 0.6, 1.8, 0.8
0.55, 0.7, 0.54, 1.79, 0.8
0.55, 0.75, 0.48, 1.78, 0.8
0.55, 0.8, 0.42, 1.77, 0.8
0.56, 0.53, 0.74, 1.83, 0.8
0.56, 0.58, 0.68, 1.82, 0.8
0.56, 0.63, 0.62, 1.81, 0.8
0.56, 0.68, 0.56, 1.8, 0.8
0.56, 0.73, 0.5, 1.79, 0.8
0.56, 0.78, 0.44, 1.78, 0.8
0.56, 0.83, 0.38, 1.77, 0.8
0.57, 0.51, 0.76, 1.84, 0.8
0.57, 0.56, 0.7, 1.83, 0.8
0.57, 0.61, 0.64, 1.82, 0.8
0.57, 0.66, 0.58, 1.81, 0.8
0.57, 0.71, 0.52, 1.8, 0.8
0.57, 0.76, 0.46, 1.79, 0.8
0.57, 0.81, 0.4, 1.78, 0.8
0.58, 0.54, 0.72, 1.84, 0.8
0.58, 0.59, 0.66, 1.83, 0.8
0.58, 0.64, 0.6, 1.82, 0.8
0.58, 0.69, 0.54, 1.81, 0.8
0.58, 0.74, 0.48, 1.8, 0.8
0.58, 0.79, 0.42, 1.79, 0.8
0.59, 0.52, 0.74, 1.85, 0.8
0.59, 0.57, 0.68, 1.84, 0.8
0.59, 0.62, 0.62, 1.83, 0.8
0.59, 0.67, 0.56, 1.82, 0.8
0.59, 0.72, 0.5, 1.81, 0.8
0.59, 0.77, 0.44, 1.8, 0.8
0.59, 0.82, 0.38, 1.79, 0.8
0.6, 0.5, 0.76, 1.86, 0.8
0.6, 0.55, 0.7, 1.85, 0.8
0.6, 0.6, 0.64, 1.84, 0.8
0.6, 0.65, 0.58, 1.83, 0.8
0.6, 0.7, 0.52, 1.82, 0.8
0.6, 0.75, 0.46, 1.81, 0.8
0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 1.8, 0.8
0.61, 0.53, 0.72, 1.86, 0.8
0.61, 0.58, 0.66, 1.85, 0.8
0.61, 0.63, 0.6, 1.84, 0.8
0.61, 0.68, 0.54, 1.83, 0.8
0.61, 0.73, 0.48, 1.82, 0.8
0.61, 0.78, 0.42, 1.81, 0.8
0.61, 0.83, 0.36, 1.8, 0.8
0.62, 0.51, 0.74, 1.87, 0.8
0.62, 0.56, 0.68, 1.86, 0.8
0.62, 0.61, 0.62, 1.85, 0.8
0.62, 0.66, 0.56, 1.84, 0.8
0.62, 0.71, 0.5, 1.83, 0.8
0.62, 0.76, 0.44, 1.82, 0.8
0.62, 0.81, 0.38, 1.81, 0.8
0.63, 0.54, 0.7, 1.87, 0.8
0.63, 0.59, 0.64, 1.86, 0.8
0.63, 0.64, 0.58, 1.85, 0.8
0.63, 0.69, 0.52, 1.84, 0.8
0.63, 0.74, 0.46, 1.83, 0.8
0.63, 0.79, 0.4, 1.82, 0.8
0.64, 0.52, 0.72, 1.88, 0.8
0.64, 0.57, 0.66, 1.87, 0.8
0.64, 0.62, 0.6, 1.86, 0.8
0.64, 0.67, 0.54, 1.85, 0.8
0.64, 0.72, 0.48, 1.84, 0.8
0.64, 0.77, 0.42, 1.83, 0.8
0.64, 0.82, 0.36, 1.82, 0.8
0.65, 0.5, 0.74, 1.89, 0.8
0.65, 0.55, 0.68, 1.88, 0.8
0.65, 0.6, 0.62, 1.87, 0.8
0.65, 0.65, 0.56, 1.86, 0.8
0.65, 0.7, 0.5, 1.85, 0.8
0.65, 0.75, 0.44, 1.84, 0.8
0.65, 0.8, 0.38, 1.83, 0.8
0.66, 0.53, 0.7, 1.89, 0.8
0.66, 0.58, 0.64, 1.88, 0.8
0.66, 0.63, 0.58, 1.87, 0.8
0.66, 0.68, 0.52, 1.86, 0.8
0.66, 0.73, 0.46, 1.85, 0.8
0.66, 0.78, 0.4, 1.84, 0.8
0.66, 0.83, 0.34, 1.83, 0.8
0.67, 0.51, 0.72, 1.9, 0.8
0.67, 0.56, 0.66, 1.89, 0.8
0.67, 0.61, 0.6, 1.88, 0.8
0.67, 0.66, 0.54, 1.87, 0.8
0.67, 0.71, 0.48, 1.86, 0.8
0.67, 0.76, 0.42, 1.85, 0.8
0.67, 0.81, 0.36, 1.84, 0.8
0.68, 0.54, 0.68, 1.9, 0.8
0.68, 0.59, 0.62, 1.89, 0.8
0.68, 0.64, 0.56, 1.88, 0.8
0.68, 0.69, 0.5, 1.87, 0.8
0.68, 0.74, 0.44, 1.86, 0.8
0.68, 0.79, 0.38, 1.85, 0.8
0.69, 0.52, 0.7, 1.91, 0.8
0.69, 0.57, 0.64, 1.9, 0.8
0.69, 0.62, 0.58, 1.89, 0.8
0.69, 0.67, 0.52, 1.88, 0.8
0.69, 0.72, 0.46, 1.87, 0.8
0.69, 0.77, 0.4, 1.86, 0.8
0.69, 0.82, 0.34, 1.85, 0.8
0.7, 0.5, 0.72, 1.92, 0.8
0.7, 0.55, 0.66, 1.91, 0.8
0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 1.9, 0.8
0.7, 0.65, 0.54, 1.89, 0.8
0.7, 0.7, 0.48, 1.88, 0.8
0.7, 0.75, 0.42, 1.87, 0.8
0.7, 0.8, 0.36, 1.86, 0.8
0.71, 0.53, 0.68, 1.92, 0.8
0.71, 0.58, 0.62, 1.91, 0.8
0.71, 0.63, 0.56, 1.9, 0.8
0.71, 0.68, 0.5, 1.89, 0.8
0.71, 0.73, 0.44, 1.88, 0.8
0.71, 0.78, 0.38, 1.87, 0.8
0.71, 0.83, 0.32, 1.86, 0.8
0.72, 0.51, 0.7, 1.93, 0.8
0.72, 0.56, 0.64, 1.92, 0.8
0.72, 0.61, 0.58, 1.91, 0.8
0.72, 0.66, 0.52, 1.9, 0.8
0.72, 0.71, 0.46, 1.89, 0.8
0.72, 0.76, 0.4, 1.88, 0.8
0.72, 0.81, 0.34, 1.87, 0.8
0.73, 0.54, 0.66, 1.93, 0.8
0.73, 0.59, 0.6, 1.92, 0.8
0.73, 0.64, 0.54, 1.91, 0.8
0.73, 0.69, 0.48, 1.9, 0.8
0.73, 0.74, 0.42, 1.89, 0.8
0.73, 0.79, 0.36, 1.88, 0.8
0.74, 0.52, 0.68, 1.94, 0.8
0.74, 0.57, 0.62, 1.93, 0.8
0.74, 0.62, 0.56, 1.92, 0.8
0.74, 0.67, 0.5, 1.91, 0.8
0.74, 0.72, 0.44, 1.9, 0.8
0.74, 0.77, 0.38, 1.89, 0.8
0.74, 0.82, 0.32, 1.88, 0.8
0.75, 0.5, 0.7, 1.95, 0.8
0.75, 0.55, 0.64, 1.94, 0.8
0.75, 0.6, 0.58, 1.93, 0.8
0.75, 0.65, 0.52, 1.92, 0.8
0.75, 0.7, 0.46, 1.91, 0.8
0.75, 0.75, 0.4, 1.9, 0.8
0.75, 0.8, 0.34, 1.89, 0.8
0.76, 0.53, 0.66, 1.95, 0.8
0.76, 0.58, 0.6, 1.94, 0.8
0.76, 0.63, 0.54, 1.93, 0.8
0.76, 0.68, 0.48, 1.92, 0.8
0.76, 0.73, 0.42, 1.91, 0.8
0.76, 0.78, 0.36, 1.9, 0.8
0.76, 0.83, 0.3, 1.89, 0.8
0.77, 0.51, 0.68, 1.96, 0.8
0.77, 0.56, 0.62, 1.95, 0.8
0.77, 0.61, 0.56, 1.94, 0.8
0.77, 0.66, 0.5, 1.93, 0.8
0.77, 0.71, 0.44, 1.92, 0.8
0.77, 0.76, 0.38, 1.91, 0.8
0.77, 0.81, 0.32, 1.9, 0.8
0.78, 0.54, 0.64, 1.96, 0.8
0.78, 0.59, 0.58, 1.95, 0.8
0.78, 0.64, 0.52, 1.94, 0.8
0.78, 0.69, 0.46, 1.93, 0.8
0.78, 0.74, 0.4, 1.92, 0.8
0.78, 0.79, 0.34, 1.91, 0.8
0.79, 0.52, 0.66, 1.97, 0.8
0.79, 0.57, 0.6, 1.96, 0.8
0.79, 0.62, 0.54, 1.95, 0.8
0.79, 0.67, 0.48, 1.94, 0.8
0.79, 0.72, 0.42, 1.93, 0.8
0.79, 0.77, 0.36, 1.92, 0.8
0.79, 0.82, 0.3, 1.91, 0.8
0.8, 0.5, 0.68, 1.98, 0.8
0.8, 0.55, 0.62, 1.97, 0.8
0.8, 0.6, 0.56, 1.96, 0.8
0.8, 0.65, 0.5, 1.95, 0.8
0.8, 0.7, 0.44, 1.94, 0.8
0.8, 0.75, 0.38, 1.93, 0.8
0.8, 0.8, 0.32, 1.92, 0.8
0.81, 0.53, 0.64, 1.98, 0.8
0.81, 0.58, 0.58, 1.97, 0.8
0.81, 0.63, 0.52, 1.96, 0.8
0.81, 0.68, 0.46, 1.95, 0.8
0.81, 0.73, 0.4, 1.94, 0.8
0.81, 0.78, 0.34, 1.93, 0.8
0.81, 0.83, 0.28, 1.92, 0.8
0.82, 0.51, 0.66, 1.99, 0.8
0.82, 0.56, 0.6, 1.98, 0.8
0.82, 0.61, 0.54, 1.97, 0.8
0.82, 0.66, 0.48, 1.96, 0.8
0.82, 0.71, 0.42, 1.95, 0.8
0.82, 0.76, 0.36, 1.94, 0.8
0.82, 0.81, 0.3, 1.93, 0.8
0.83, 0.54, 0.62, 1.99, 0.8
0.83, 0.59, 0.56, 1.98, 0.8
0.83, 0.64, 0.5, 1.97, 0.8
0.83, 0.69, 0.44, 1.96, 0.8
0.83, 0.74, 0.38, 1.95, 0.8
0.83, 0.79, 0.32, 1.94, 0.8
0.84, 0.52, 0.64, 2.0, 0.8
0.84, 0.57, 0.58, 1.99, 0.8
0.84, 0.62, 0.52, 1.98, 0.8
0.84, 0.67, 0.46, 1.97, 0.8
0.84, 0.72, 0.4, 1.96, 0.8
0.84, 0.77, 0.34, 1.95, 0.8
0.84, 0.82, 0.28, 1.94, 0.8
0.85, 0.5, 0.66, 2.01, 0.8
0.85, 0.55, 0.6, 2.0, 0.8
0.85, 0.6, 0.54, 1.99, 0.8
0.85, 0.65, 0.48, 1.98, 0.8
0.85, 0.7, 0.42, 1.97, 0.8
0.85, 0.75, 0.36, 1.96, 0.8
0.85, 0.8, 0.3, 1.95, 0.8
0.86, 0.53, 0.62, 2.01, 0.8
0.86, 0.58, 0.56, 2.0, 0.8
0.86, 0.63, 0.5, 1.99, 0.8
0.86, 0.68, 0.44, 1.98, 0.8
0.86, 0.73, 0.38, 1.97, 0.8
0.86, 0.78, 0.32, 1.96, 0.8
0.86, 0.83, 0.26, 1.95, 0.8
0.87, 0.51, 0.64, 2.02, 0.8
0.87, 0.56, 0.58, 2.01, 0.8
0.87, 0.61, 0.52, 2.0, 0.8
0.87, 0.66, 0.46, 1.99, 0.8
0.87, 0.71, 0.4, 1.98, 0.8
0.87, 0.76, 0.34, 1.97, 0.8
0.87, 0.81, 0.28, 1.96, 0.8
0.88, 0.54, 0.6, 2.02, 0.8
0.88, 0.59, 0.54, 2.01, 0.8
0.88, 0.64, 0.48, 2.0, 0.8
0.88, 0.69, 0.42, 1.99, 0.8
0.88, 0.74, 0.36, 1.98, 0.8
0.88, 0.79, 0.3, 1.97, 0.8
0.89, 0.52, 0.62, 2.03, 0.8
0.89, 0.57, 0.56, 2.02, 0.8
0.89, 0.62, 0.5, 2.01, 0.8
0.89, 0.67, 0.44, 2.0, 0.8
0.89, 0.72, 0.38, 1.99, 0.8
0.89, 0.77, 0.32, 1.98, 0.8
0.89, 0.82, 0.26, 1.97, 0.8
0.9, 0.5, 0.64, 2.04, 0.8
0.9, 0.55, 0.58, 2.03, 0.8
0.9, 0.6, 0.52, 2.02, 0.8
0.9, 0.65, 0.46, 2.01, 0.8
0.9, 0.7, 0.4, 2.0, 0.8
0.9, 0.75, 0.34, 1.99, 0.8
0.9, 0.8, 0.28, 1.98, 0.8
0.91, 0.53, 0.6, 2.04, 0.8
0.91, 0.58, 0.54, 2.03, 0.8
0.91, 0.63, 0.48, 2.02, 0.8
0.91, 0.68, 0.42, 2.01, 0.8
0.91, 0.73, 0.36, 2.0, 0.8
0.91, 0.78, 0.3, 1.99, 0.8
0.91, 0.83, 0.24, 1.98, 0.8
0.92, 0.51, 0.62, 2.05, 0.8
0.92, 0.56, 0.56, 2.04, 0.8
0.92, 0.61, 0.5, 2.03, 0.8
0.92, 0.66, 0.44, 2.02, 0.8
0.92, 0.71, 0.38, 2.01, 0.8
0.92, 0.76, 0.32, 2.0, 0.8
0.92, 0.81, 0.26, 1.99, 0.8
0.93, 0.54, 0.58, 2.05, 0.8
0.93, 0.59, 0.52, 2.04, 0.8
0.93, 0.64, 0.46, 2.03, 0.8
0.93, 0.69, 0.4, 2.02, 0.8
0.93, 0.74, 0.34, 2.01, 0.8
0.93, 0.79, 0.28, 2.0, 0.8
0.94, 0.52, 0.6, 2.06, 0.8
0.94, 0.57, 0.54, 2.05, 0.8
0.94, 0.62, 0.48, 2.04, 0.8
0.94, 0.67, 0.42, 2.03, 0.8
0.94, 0.72, 0.36, 2.02, 0.8
0.94, 0.77, 0.3, 2.01, 0.8
0.94, 0.82, 0.24, 2.0, 0.8
0.95, 0.5, 0.62, 2.07, 0.8
0.95, 0.55, 0.56, 2.06, 0.8
0.95, 0.6, 0.5, 2.05, 0.8
0.95, 0.65, 0.44, 2.04, 0.8
0.95, 0.7, 0.38, 2.03, 0.8
0.95, 0.75, 0.32, 2.02, 0.8
0.95, 0.8, 0.26, 2.01, 0.8
0.96, 0.53, 0.58, 2.07, 0.8
0.96, 0.58, 0.52, 2.06, 0.8
0.96, 0.63, 0.46, 2.05, 0.8
0.96, 0.68, 0.4, 2.04, 0.8
0.96, 0.73, 0.34, 2.03, 0.8
0.96, 0.78, 0.28, 2.02, 0.8
0.96, 0.83, 0.22, 2.01, 0.8
0.97, 0.51, 0.6, 2.08, 0.8
0.97, 0.56, 0.54, 2.07, 0.8
0.97, 0.61, 0.48, 2.06, 0.8
0.97, 0.66, 0.42, 2.05, 0.8
0.97, 0.71, 0.36, 2.04, 0.8
0.97, 0.76, 0.3, 2.03, 0.8
0.97, 0.81, 0.24, 2.02, 0.8
0.98, 0.54, 0.56, 2.08, 0.8
0.98, 0.59, 0.5, 2.07, 0.8
0.98, 0.64, 0.44, 2.06, 0.8
0.98, 0.69, 0.38, 2.05, 0.8
0.98, 0.74, 0.32, 2.04, 0.8
0.98, 0.79, 0.26, 2.03, 0.8
0.99, 0.52, 0.58, 2.09, 0.8
0.99, 0.57, 0.52, 2.08, 0.8
0.99, 0.62, 0.46, 2.07, 0.8
0.99, 0.67, 0.4, 2.06, 0.8
0.99, 0.72, 0.34, 2.05, 0.8
0.99, 0.77, 0.28, 2.04, 0.8
0.99, 0.82, 0.22, 2.03, 0.8
```

It seems that the closest solution is:  $w_1=0$, $w_2=0.9$, $w_3=0.52$, which gives the sum $w_1+w_2+w_3=1.42$, and maintains $t=0.8$.

Among all of the runs, I found this: $w_1=0$, $w_2=0.29$, $w_3=0.99$, $w_1+w_2+w_3=1.28$, $t=0.669$ --- is this a good compromise? (just an example).

Is there a mathematical method in identifying a solution that generally minimizes the error $((w_1+w_2+w_3) - 1)^2 + (t-0.8)^2$. Feel free to propose an alternative error metric.

### A preliminary guess of mine:

How about finding $w_1,w_2,w_3$ that minimize $\Big(\big((w_1+w_2+w_3) - 1\big)^2 + (t-0.8)^2\Big)$?

Is there a way to do this using calculus?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses

Comment: @JKnecht, thanks. I added answers using some code that I wrote. It's not mathematical, but I hope it gives an idea what I wish to know.

Comment: Using the numbers you supplied, the highest possible value of $t$ is 0.6, where the sum of the $w$s is 1, $w_i$={0, 1, 0}. If you want $t=0.8$ the best values for $w_i$ are {0, 1 1/3, 0}. If $w_i$ can be below zero, then a solution is $w_i$ = {0, 3, -2}. You can't get an exact answer unless you relax at least one of your restrictions. How are you defining error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first observation is that the closest you can get to $t=0.8$ while keeping your other restrictions is if $w_2=1$ and $w_1=w_3=0$. Increasing either of $w_1$ or $w_3$ means decreasing $w_2$ to keep the sum at $1$, which also decreases the value of $t$.

If you are trying to find the minimal value of $\left(w_1+w_2+w_3-1\right)^2+\left(t-0.8\right)^2$ you can so do with the following:

The closest answer will always be where $w_1=w_3=0$, so I have eliminated them to start off with.

$$(w_2-1)^2+(0.6w_2-0.8)^2$$

$$w_2^2-2w_2+1+0.36w_2^2-0.96w_2+0.64$$

$$1.36w_2^2-2.96w_2+1.64$$

This curve is a parabola above 0. We want to find the point on the curve where it is closest to 0. This is where the curve changes from negative to positive. To do this we find where the derivative of the curve is 0:

$$2.72w_2-2.96=0$$

$$2.72w_2=2.96$$

$$34w_2=37$$

$$w_2={37 \over 34} \approx 1.088235294$$

So, your answer is $w_i=[0, {37 \over 34}, 0]$ giving $t={111 \over 170}\approx 0.652941176$. The error is ${1 \over 34}\approx 0.029411765$

---

If, however, you absolutely require all values of $w_i$ to be between 0 and 1, an alternative solution can be worked out like this:

Set $w_2$ to 1, $w_1$ to 0 and work out the best fit for $w_3$:

$$(1+w_3-1)^2+(0.6+0.5w_3-0.8)^2$$

$$(w_3 )^2+(0.5w_3-0.2)^2$$

$$w_3^2+0.25w_3^2-0.2w_3+0.04$$

$$1.25w_3^2-0.2w_3+0.04$$

We use the same derivative method to find the closest point to 0:

$$2.5w_3-0.2=0$$

$$2.5w_3=0.2$$

$$25w_3=2$$

$$w_3={2\over 25}$$

Now the answer is $w_i=[0, 1, 0.08]$ giving $t={16 \over 25}= 0.64$. The error is only slightly higher at ${4 \over 125}= 0.032$.

Comment: Very nice. Minor nitpick: $w_2$ is constrained to be less than 1, so the optimal value happens at $(0,1,0)$. The geometry of the situation suggests to me that if there is no solution then it is always optimized by one of the three vertices $w_i=1$, but I need to go to sleep for now.

Comment: @EricStucky I wrote a comment on the question stating that this problem is not exactly answerable without relaxing at least one restriction. If the OP gives me feedback that $w_2$ can't be higher than 1 (i.e. that rule is more important than the others), I will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: @EricStucky OK, so I decided to proactively edit my answer based on your comment!

Comment: @CJDennis, thank you very much! I have a few extra questions: (Q1) By your 2nd answer, you satisfied $w_i \in [0,1]$ at the cost of violating $\sum_{i \in \{1,2,3\}} w_i = 1$ am I right? (Q2) You have eliminated $w_1$ and $w_3$ at some point to make the solution easier, such that at any point you differentiated a system with a single unknown. My question is: how would you do this if you could not assume that $w_1 = w_3 = 0$ early on? I.e. is there any systematic way to solve for the case when such easy shortcuts don't exist?

Comment: @caveman 1) Yes, you are correct. The sum of $w_i$ is now 1.08. 2) If all of your conditions were met simultaneously, you would either have a single solution (an edge case) or an infinite number of solutions within a small range. You would need an additional criterion to select one of those solutions.

Comment: @CJDennis, thank you. Can you please address my (Q2)?

Comment: @caveman If $t=0.4$ and the remainder of your conditions are satisfied there are now an infinite number of solutions. Which one is "best"? You need to further define "best" in order to come up with a single solution. If $w_3=0.2$, then $w_1=0.45$ and $w_2=0.35$. Changing any of $w_i$ will change _both_ of the other values. In fact, setting any one of $w_i$ immediately defines the other two. You can use your original definitions as simultaneous equations to work out the other two values. If you add a third definition then you will have enough simultaneous equations to work out all of them.

Comment: @CJDennis, so fascinating.. Is this called _multi-variate calculus_ or something? One keyword I learn  is _solving simultaneous equations_. Could you please tell me what should I read? :) Sorry for being too stupid. Thank you very much for helping me. You are such a hero.

Comment: @caveman It's been a long time since I did maths at school and while I enjoy maths and I'm good at it I often don't know what the methods are called. I would suggest searching this site and the internet for the terms you're not familiar with and if you still don't understand, ask another question on this site. Good luck! I hope you find the additional information you want.

Answer (score 1):

I will keep it all strict and you see if that answers your question:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{3} w_{k}=1 \implies w_{1}=1-w_{2}-w_{3}$$

$$w_{1}f_{1}+w_{2}f_{2}+w_{3}f_{3}=t$$
$$f_{1}+w_{2}(f_{2}-f_{1})+w_{3}(f_{3}-f_{1})=t$$

Now $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}$ do not have any special connection between them so we can simply replace $f'_{2}=f_{2}-f_{1}$ and $f'_{3}=f_{3}-f_{1}$, taking $f'_{2}$ and $f'_{3}$ to be another set of constants. (In your case you can calculate their values, but in the equation we consider them constants in contrast to $w_{2}$ and $w_{3}$.)

$$f_{1}+f'_{2}w_{2}+f'_{3}w_{3}=t$$

This simply makes a function
$$w_{3}(w_{2})= -\frac{f'_{2}}{f'_{3}}w_{2}+\frac{t-f_{1}}{f'_{3}}$$

If this functions goes through the quadrant $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ then we have many solutions which you can restrict further.

If it does not then since $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ are restricted to $[0,1]$, depending on the angle of $w_{3}(w_{2})$ in general the best choice is one of $(w_{3},w_{2}) \in \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ unless you impose other restrictions over them. One of these points is closest to the quadrant.

There are a few special cases like $f'_{3}=0$ but you can either avoid this by making another less problematic choice or you can analyze it as it is.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was following up smoothly until I hit the part on _independent_. I don't understand what _independent_ means here, nor that I understand why it matters in anything. I guess I am lacking knowledge of some fundamental concept. Could you please guide me on what to read so that I nail this once and for all? (or if you feel more generous then you might as well spoon-feed me right here) -- thank you very much again!

Comment: Nothing special indeed, just the fact that we can consider another set of constants. In edited.

Answer (score 1):

The first and the last conditions define
$t$ as a 
[convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination)
of $f_i$. 
Since $t$ is a scalar as well as each $f_i$, 
we can consider them as $x$-coordinates 
of points on a line segment $[0,1]$.

Let
\begin{align}
 a&=\min_i(f_i),\  
 b=\max_i(f_i).
\end{align}

If $t<a$ or $t>b$ then 
there is no valid solution for $w_i\in[0,1]$.
This is the case in the original question, $a=0.2,b=0.6,t=0.8$,
hence no solution. 
The closest solution would be a set of $w_i$
that results in the point $t'\in[a,b]$, which is closest to $t$, 
i.e. $t'=0.6$.

In case when $t\in[a,b]$, $t=a(1-s)+b$ for some real $s\in[0,1]$, 
an obvious choice for $w_i$ would be
values 
$1-s$ (for the minimal $f_i$),
$s$ (for the maximal $f_i$)
and $0$ for the other $f_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first two of your questions:

You have 3 variables and two linear equations. You can solve this equation system on the classical way by hand or in matrix form. See e.g. Wikipedia System of linear equations

The solutions of the equation system are:

\begin{equation}w_{1}=\frac{w_{2}}{3}-1,\ w_{3}=2-\frac{4w_{2}}{3}\end{equation}